# "Troubleshooting Missing HTTP-Only Refresh Token Cookie in Application"

Tags: reactjs, express, jwt, refresh-token

Im currently have a test application that Im trying to use for my real project that I'm presently working on. I've used create react app to make a simple react project. I have a login page with input fields designed to register new users and another to login existing users, [my login Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivTru.png).

When the user logs in or registers's their account they are takin to a home page which consists of a counter button, a paragraph div to display the current count, and a logout button, [my homepage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3gxf.png). When the counter button is clicked it makes a call to the backend at the 'counter' endpoint which first verifies the accessToken the user is currently using (which in this case only lasts 30s) so that they can increment the count by one and save it in the user's object in the users.json file in my backend.

Initially everything works fine I register the user I start incrementing, clicking the button and the number increases, then after the 30s are up is when he problem occurs. The refresh-token which was sent as a cookie in the front end isn't being re-sent to the backend. I know that the front end is getting the cookie despite the 'not-secure' tag in the address field because firstly I designed the cookie's security to be false since I'm in development and for sameSite I've used both None and lax as the value, since both my front end and backend are on https but are on local host 3000 and 5500 respectively, and both values have worked because when i look at the Network in the dev tools and go to the register route I can see the refreshToken cookie [refreshToken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbMms.png). But the application area, when I go to the cookie tab there is nothing,[Application cookie area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qUbm5.png). For my refresh function in the backend I made a console log to check what was being sent from req.cookie and I got a, '[Object: null prototype] {}'.

I don't understand why the backend isn't getting the cookie back or why its not being put in the currently running application's cookie area I've been going at this for I don't know how long and I don't know this isn't working. Someone please help me.

My App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Routes, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import HomePage from './components/HomePage';
import LoginPage from './components/LoginPage';
import { BlackBoardProvider } from './components/BlackBoardContext';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <BlackBoardProvider>
        <div className='App'>
            <Routes>
              <Route path='/' element={<LoginPage />} />
              <Route path='/home' element={<HomePage />} />
            </Routes>
        </div>
      </BlackBoardProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

my contextAPI:

```
import React, {createContext, useState, useRef} from 'react';

export const BlackBoardContext = createContext();

export const BlackBoardProvider = ({children}) => {
    const baseURL = process.env.REACT_APP_SERVER_URL;
  

    return (
        <BlackBoardContext.Provider value = {{
            baseURL
        }}>
            {children}
        </BlackBoardContext.Provider>
    );
};
```

My loginPage:

```
import React, { useContext, useState } from 'react';
import { BlackBoardContext } from './BlackBoardContext';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const LoginPage = () => {
  const { baseURL } = useContext(BlackBoardContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate(); 

  const [loginForm, setLoginForm] = useState({
    userEmail: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const [registerForm, setRegisterForm] = useState({
    userEmail: '',
    password: '',
  });

  const inputLogin = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setLoginForm({ ...loginForm, [name]: value });
  };

  const inputRegister = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    setRegisterForm({ ...registerForm, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleLogin = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const url = `${baseURL}/login`;
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(loginForm),
      };
      const loginResponse = await fetch(url, options);
      if (!loginResponse.ok) {
        throw new Error('Login failed');
      }
      const loginData = await loginResponse.json();
      if (loginData) {
        const { accessToken } = loginData
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);

        navigate('/home');
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Login error:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleRegister = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();

    try {
      const url = `${baseURL}/register`;
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          userEmail: registerForm.userEmail,
          password: registerForm.password,
        }),
      };
      const registerResponse = await fetch(url, options);
      if (!registerResponse.ok) {
        throw new Error('Registration failed');
      }
      const registerData = await registerResponse.json();
      if (registerData) {
        const { accessToken } = registerData
        localStorage.setItem('accessToken', accessToken);
            
        navigate('/home'); 
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Registration error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <form onSubmit={handleLogin}>

        <input className='user-email' placeholder='email' name='userEmail'
          value={loginForm.userEmail} onChange={inputLogin} type='email' required/>
          
        <input className='password' placeholder='password' name='password'
          value={loginForm.password} onChange={inputLogin} type='password' required/>

        <button>Login</button>
      </form>

      <form onSubmit={handleRegister}>

        <input className='user-email' placeholder='email' name='userEmail'
         value={registerForm.userEmail} onChange={inputRegister} type='email'required/>

        <input className='password' placeholder='password' name='password'
        value={registerForm.password} onChange={inputRegister} type='password' required/>

        <button>register</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default LoginPage;
```

my homepage:

```
import React, { useState, useContext, useEffect } from 'react';
import { BlackBoardContext } from './BlackBoardContext';
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const HomePage = () => {
  const { baseURL } = useContext(BlackBoardContext);
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const [count, setCount] = useState(1); 

  const increaseCount = async () => {
    const url = `${baseURL}/counter`;
  
    const makeRequest = async (accessToken) => {
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
        },
        credentials: 'include',
        body: JSON.stringify({ count }),
      };
      const response = await fetch(url, options);
      return response;
    };
  
    const refreshAccessToken = async () => {
      const refreshUrl = `${baseURL}/refresh-token`; 
      console.log('message before the response of refreshAccessToken')
      const response = await fetch(refreshUrl, {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include', 
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        console.log('It didnt refresh fam')
        throw new Error('Failed to refresh token');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      localStorage.setItem('accessToken', data.accessToken);
      return data.accessToken;
    };
  
    try {
      let response = await makeRequest(localStorage.getItem('accessToken'));
      if (response.status === 401 || response.status === 403) {
        console.log('attempt to get refresh')
        const newAccessToken = await refreshAccessToken();
        response = await makeRequest(newAccessToken);
      }
      if (!response.ok) {
        throw new Error('Failed to increment count after refreshing token');
      }
      const data = await response.json();
      setCount(data.count);
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Increase count error:', error);
    }
  };

  const handleLogout = async () => {
    try {
      const url = `${baseURL}/logout`;
      const options = {
        method: 'POST',
        credentials: 'include', 
      };
      await fetch(url, options);
     
      localStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
      navigate('/');
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Logout error:', error);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={increaseCount}>Counter</button> 
      <p>{count}</p>
      <button onClick={handleLogout}>Logout</button> 
    </div>
  );
};

export default HomePage;
```

my server.js:

```
const express = require('express');
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const fsPromises = require('fs').promises;
const path = require('path');
const bcrypt = require('bcrypt');
const cors = require('cors');
const { v4: uuidv4 } = require('uuid');
const https = require('https');
require('dotenv').config({ path: path.resolve(__dirname, '.env') });
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(cookieParser());
const corsOptions = {
  origin: 'https://localhost:3000', 
  credentials: true, 
  methods: 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS', 
  allowedHeaders: 'Content-Type, Authorization', 
};
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

async function loadCredentials() {
  const privateKeyPath = path.join(__dirname, '../key.pem')
  const certificatePath = path.join(__dirname, '../cert.pem');

  try {
    const privateKey = await fsPromises.readFile(privateKeyPath, 'utf8');
    const certificate = await fsPromises.readFile(certificatePath, 'utf8');
    return { key: privateKey, cert: certificate };
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error loading credentials:', error);
    throw error; 
  }
}

async function startHttpsServer() {
  try {
    const credentials = await loadCredentials();
    const httpsServer = https.createServer(credentials, app);

    const PORT = 5500;
    httpsServer.listen(PORT, () => {
      console.log(`HTTPS Server running on port ${PORT}`);
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Failed to start HTTPS server:', error);
  }
}

const USERS_FILE = path.join(__dirname, './users.json');

const verifyToken = (req, res, next) => {
  const authHeader = req.headers.authorization;
  const token = authHeader && authHeader.split(' ')[1];
  if (!token) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'Access token is missing' });
  }
  jwt.verify(token, process.env.JWT_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
    if (err) {
      return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Token is not valid or has expired' });
    }
    req.user = decoded;
    next();
  });
};

app.post('/login', async (req, res) => {
  const { userEmail, password } = req.body;
  try {
      const users = JSON.parse(await fsPromises.readFile(USERS_FILE, 'utf8'));
      const user = users.find(u => u.userEmail === userEmail);
      if (!user) {
          return res.status(404).send('Account not found.');
      }
      const isMatch = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.userPassword);
      if (!isMatch) {
          return res.status(401).send('Invalid password.');
      }
      const tokenPayload = { id: user.id, userEmail: user.userEmail };
      const accessToken = jwt.sign(tokenPayload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '30s' });
      const refreshToken = jwt.sign(tokenPayload, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' });
      const updatedUsers = users.map(u => {
        if (u.id === user.id) {
          return { ...u, refreshToken };
        }
        return u;
      });
      await fsPromises.writeFile(USERS_FILE, JSON.stringify(updatedUsers, null, 2), 'utf8');
      res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, { httpOnly: true, secure: false, sameSite: 'lax', maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 });
            res.status(200).json({
        valid: true,
        message: 'Login successful.',
        userId: user.id,
        userEmail: user.userEmail,
        accessToken: accessToken,
        counter: user.counter || 0 
      });
  } catch (err) {
      console.error("Error handling login:", err);
      res.status(500).send('An error occurred during login.');
  }
});

app.post('/register', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const data = await fsPromises.readFile(USERS_FILE, 'utf8');
    let users = JSON.parse(data);
    console.log(req.body.password); 
    const hashedPassword = await bcrypt.hash(req.body.password, 10);

    const newUser = {
      id: uuidv4(),
      userEmail: req.body.userEmail, 
      userPassword: hashedPassword,
      counter: 1, 
      refreshToken: ''
    };

    const tokenPayload = { id: newUser.id, userEmail: newUser.userEmail };
    const accessToken = jwt.sign(tokenPayload, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '30s' });
    const refreshToken = jwt.sign(tokenPayload, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, { expiresIn: '7d' });
    newUser.refreshToken = refreshToken;

    users.push(newUser);
    await fsPromises.writeFile(USERS_FILE, JSON.stringify(users, null, 2), 'utf8');
    res.cookie('refreshToken', refreshToken, {
      httpOnly: true, 
      secure: false,  
      sameSite: 'None',
      maxAge: 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000 
    });
        res.status(201).json({ valid: true, accessToken: accessToken, user: { id: newUser.id, userEmail: newUser.userEmail, counter: newUser.counter } });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error processing request:", err);
    res.status(500).send('An error occurred during account creation.');
  }
});

app.post('/refresh-token', async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.cookies)
  const { refreshToken } = req.cookies;
  if (!refreshToken) {
    return res.status(401).json({ error: 'No refresh token provided' });
  }
  try {
    const users = JSON.parse(await fsPromises.readFile(USERS_FILE, 'utf8'));
    const user = users.find(u => u.refreshToken === refreshToken);
    if (!user) {
      return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Invalid refresh token' });
    }
    jwt.verify(refreshToken, process.env.REFRESH_TOKEN_SECRET, (err, decoded) => {
      if (err || user.id !== decoded.id) {
        return res.status(403).json({ error: 'Token verification failed' });
      }
      const newAccessToken = jwt.sign({ id: user.id, userEmail: user.userEmail }, process.env.JWT_SECRET, { expiresIn: '30s' });
      res.status(200).json({
        valid: true,
        message: 'Access token refreshed successfully',
        accessToken: newAccessToken
      });
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error refreshing token:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to refresh token' });
  }
});

app.post('/logout', (req, res) => {
  res.clearCookie('refreshToken');

  res.status(200).json({ message: 'Logged out successfully' });
});

app.post('/counter', verifyToken, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    console.log('start counter')
    const users = JSON.parse(await fsPromises.readFile(USERS_FILE, 'utf8'));
    const userIndex = users.findIndex(u => u.id === req.user.id);
    if (userIndex === -1) {
      return res.status(404).json({ error: 'User not found' });
    }
    users[userIndex].counter = (users[userIndex].counter || 0) + 1;
    await fsPromises.writeFile(USERS_FILE, JSON.stringify(users, null, 2), 'utf8');
    res.json({ count: users[userIndex].counter });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error("Error handling counter increment:", err);
    res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to increment counter' });
  }
});

startHttpsServer();
```